# Will the foreign legion disappear if I switch ideology in Civilization 5 Brave New World

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Say I have chosen the Volunteer Army from Freedom ideology. Will the summoned troops disappear if I then switch the ideology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it won't. No unit can forcedly disband in any way, except by Gold deficit.